# pandas: Keep only every row that has cumulated change by a threshold?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm interested to extract the rows where a column's value has either gone up cumulatively by at least 5 or gone down cumulatively by at least 5, then get the signs of these cumulative changes, `up_or_down`.

For example, let's say I want to apply this to column `y` in the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(16), 'y': [1,10,14,12,13,9,4,2,6,7,10,11,16,17,14,11]})
```

It should yield:

```
x   y        # up_or_down
1   10       # +1
6   4        # -1
10  10       # +1
12  16       # +1
15  11       # -1
```

My dataframe is quite large so I was hoping that there is a nice vectorized way to do this natively with pandas's API rather than looping through it with `iterrows()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the core of the solution

```
def big_diff(y):
    val = y.values
    r = val[0]
    for i, x in enumerate(val):
        d = r - x
        if abs(d) >= 5:
            yield i, 1 if d < 0 else -1
            r = x
```

Then you can do something like this

```
slc = np.array(list(big_diff(df.y)))
df_slcd = pd.DataFrame(df.values[slc[:, 0]], df.index[slc[:, 0]], df.columns)
signs = pd.Series(slc[:, 1], df.index[slc[:, 0]], name='up_or_down')

df_slcd
```

[image]

```
signs

1     1
6    -1
10    1
12    1
15   -1
Name: up_or_down, dtype: int64
```

---

```
pd.concat([df_slcd, signs], axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't get it vectorized through the standard functions pandas exposed: the nth point to find moving by +/-5 from n-1th is dynamically found and will depend on the position of n-1th, which itself depends on the n-2 first dynamically determined points. Thus there is no math associated to rolling or expanding set of functions that can project you in a vector space requiring this dynamism. So you have to write you iteration ad-hoc.